# How to #define function-like macro of the function with variable arguments in C

Tags: c, macros

I have a function declared as:

```
int func(int a, int b, ...);
```

Then I want to #define a function-like macro as:

```
#define TEST(A,B) func(A,B,0)
```

But the compiler always complains: "error: expected declaration specifiers or '...', before numeric constant".

So, how can I eliminate this error?

Comment: It might be because the compiler doesn't know how to express `0` in a vararg since there's no type information to match against. Try `(int) 0`.

Comment: @tadman, nop, not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the function is defined before the #define statement (could be imported too) so the compiler will the data type of a and b. Or you could also try type defining a and b as (int) a.

Comment: Oops, I know why. there's another declaration ```int func(int a, int b);```, which is the case.